# Weird thing: Cannot change UIWebView.origin.x in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview, infinite

I'm digging on infinite loop UIWebViews which are in a UIScrollView, and I tried to replace the webview with another, but failed. The currWebView.frame.origin.x cannot be modified in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if endDragOffset > 0 {
        // moving forward, get next
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.x > mainScrollView!.frame.size.width) {
            prevWebView = currWebView // get the content of the next one
            currWebView = nextWebView

            // set back the position
            prevWebView.frame.origin.x = 0
            currWebView.frame.origin.x = 320
            nextWebView.frame.origin.x = 640

            var theNext = getNext(nextVolume, theChapter: nextChapter)
            nextVolume = theNext["volume"]!
            nextChapter = theNext["chapter"]!
            nextChapterArr = getLection(nextVolume, theChapter: nextChapter)
            loadPage(nextVolume, theChapter: nextChapter, chapterArr: nextChapterArr, onPage: 2)

            print(currWebView.frame.origin.x) // got 640

            currWebView.frame.origin.x = 320
            print(currWebView.frame.origin.x) // still got 640
        }

        // moving backward, get previous
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.x < mainScrollView!.frame.size.width) {
            //.........
        }
```

and any other suggestion on making infinite webview in UISCrollView?

Answer (score 0):

Using following codes can solve the problem

```
let frame = nextWebView.frame
nextWebView.frame = currWebView.frame
currWebView.frame = prevWebView.frame
prevWebView.frame = frame
```